# unable to import PDFmake in angular8?

Tags: angular, angular8, pdfmake

i am trying to develop converting a angular form to PDF in my application , i have seen an example in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pdfmake-npm-naxmgs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) but when i try to follow the same code in my local, import are not working ?
error is `could not find the declaration for  "pdfmake/build/pdfmake"`

```
import pdfMake from "pdfmake/build/pdfmake";
import pdfFonts from "pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts";
pdfMake.vfs = pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs;
```

Update:
i have tried installing "@types/pdfmake" to fix this. it fixed partially but throwing error at "pdfmake.vfs" saying `cannot assign to vfs because it is readonly property`

```
import * as pdfMake from "pdfmake/build/pdfmake";
import * as  pdfFonts from "pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts";
pdfMake.vfs= pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs;
```

Comment: Can you check if packages are installed and referenced correctly? You can check package.json

Comment: @anandshukla installed correctly but when i need to check the reference ?

Comment: stackblitz sample is in angular8. It should work.

Comment: Is issue closed ?

Answer (score 1):

please try this, it works for me :

```
import * as pdfMake from "pdfmake/build/pdfmake";
import * as pdfFonts from 'pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts';
(pdfMake as any).vfs = pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs;
```